# I can't publish my WebRole anymore? There is not enough space on the disk?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have been publishing this webrole without issue and all of a sudden I now get this error:

```
There is not enough space on the disk.

  <CSPack
      ServiceDefinitionFile="@(TargetServiceDefinition)"
      Output="@(PublishServicePackage)"
      PackRoles="@(Roles)"
      SiteMapping="@(SiteMapping)"
      RoleProperties="@(RoleProperties)"
      ImportedModules="@(ImportedModules)"
      CopyOnly="false"
      >
    </CSPack>
```

I have tried everything I can find that seems relevant:
http://southworks.com/blog/2011/08/04/not-enough-space-on-the-disk-windows-azure/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/07/18/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-windows-azure-web-role-asp-net-temporary-folder.aspx

I even deleted my CloudServices and started with a new Cloud Service and a different new storage.

Still no luck.

Anyone else run into this and get it figured out?

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you get this error, and where is the error being displayed? Is this a packaging/publishing error, or is this an error coming from within your role code running on the VM?

Comment: This happens when I goto publish the WebRole, this error is displayed in Visual Studio - the CSPack stuff is not show in the error, there is just a reference to that line of code.

Comment: Can you create a package separately?  Instead of select Publish within Visual Studio, select Package.  Then try to deploy the .CSPKG from the management portal.